# Adding a 2nd UIToolBar for Keyboard used with UITextViews

Tags: swift3, uitextview, uitoolbar, uikeyboard, xcode8.2

I currently have a working `UIToolbar` where I'm putting extra buttons above the keyboard when using a `UITextField` but I was wanting to make a 2nd `UIToolbar` type for above a `UITextView`. When I tried copying my code and modifying it to be how I'd like it to look, it doesn't show up at all. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it has something to do with the `NotificationCenter` and `addObserver` I'm using. FYI, the overall class is called `AddRecipeDirectionVC: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate` if that is needed at all.

So here is the observer code I'm adding into my `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //...Other Code...

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AddRecipeDirectionVC.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}
```

Originally, I thought I had to add this Observer on each `UIViewController`, but I'm starting to think this code I'm using could just be put in the initial VC and it would carry out for the rest of the project (currently, I'm using that code in ever VC where I'm adding the Toolbar)

Next, I have the `textViewDidBeginEditing` function where I think the keyboard toolbar is being added.

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    if (textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray) {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
    self.keyboardToolbar(textView: textView) //Adding Keyboard
}
```

And then finally, I have `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardToolbar` functions

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {

    let keyFrame = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let keyHeight = keyFrame.size.height

    self.bottomSpace.constant = keyHeight + 12
}

func keyboardToolbar(textView: UITextView) {

    let toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolbar.bounds.size.height = 28

    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image:  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Done Check"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(AddRecipeIngredientVC.doneButtonAction))
    done.tintColor = UIColor.aqua(alpha: 1.0)

    let clear: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(AddRecipeDirectionVC.clearButtonAction))
    clear.tintColor = UIColor.darkAqua(alpha: 1)

    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

    items.append(clear)
    items.append(flexSpace)
    items.append(done)

    toolbar.items = items
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    textView.inputAccessoryView = toolbar    }

func doneButtonAction() {

    self.directionText.resignFirstResponder()
    self.bottomSpace.constant = 12
}

func clearButtonAction() {

    directionText.text = ""
}
```

As far as I can tell, I'm doing everything the same as in the other VC's, so it seems like it should be working, but nothing ever shows up. Let me know if any additional code needs to be added.

Thank you in advanced for any help anyone can give me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling, I found out that the `keyboardToolbar` code had to be put in `textViewShouldBeginEditing` not `textViewDidBeginEditing`. From what I understand, with a `UITextView` the layout has already been set once it gets to `textViewDidBeginEditing`, hence the reason I wasn't seeing it. This is the code I ended up using that did the job. Everything else is the same beside what is shown below.

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {

    self.keyboardToolbar(textView: textView)
    return true
}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    if (textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray) {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
func keyboardToolbar(textView: UITextView) {

    let toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolbar.bounds.size.height = 28

    let flexSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)


    let done: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonActionn))
    done.tintColor = UIColor.red

    let clear: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Clear", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneButtonAction))
    clear.tintColor = UIColor.black


    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()

    items.append(clear)
    items.append(flexSpace)

    items.append(done)

    toolbar.items = items
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    textView.inputAccessoryView = toolbar


}


func doneButtonAction() {

    self.bodyTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    //self.bottomSpace.constant = 12
}

func doneButtonActionn() {

    self.bodyTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    //self.bottomSpace.constant = 12
}

func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {

    self.keyboardToolbar(textView: textView)
    return true
}
```